# WP: add extra Actions on user registration

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, registration

I have a new table in my WordPress database designed to store Affiliate member information. All new users to sign up will automatically be given an Affiliate ID.

How do I make it so that when a new user signs up, not only are they registered on the site as authors but some information like their author ID and also some custom field information is also added to the affiliate table?

thanks

Comment: If the information is already in WP database, all you have to do is figure out the appropriate queries to extract it when required. Don't need to duplicate the information, any table is equally accessible. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this automatically, you could overwrite the function

```
wp_new_user_notification
```

You can find the original function in the file

```
wp-includes/pluggable.php
```

It's called after a user registers and there are no errors in the registration.

Comment: Any reason why this is down voted? The function is set up to be overwritten.

Comment: I found a solution with the add action add_action('register_user','functionToRun')